# Blank screen after updating the Compilesdkversion from 27 to 29

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin

i have updated my compileSdkversion from 27 to 29 and my app shows a blank screen i don't know why, when i reset it to sdk 27 it works fine and this is my build.gradle :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mai.xapkinstaller"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 98
        versionName "4.9"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.nononsenseapps:filepicker:4.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:$anko_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.+'

}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

i need to know what i have done wrong please help me with this issue i'm stuck for more than 48hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use *Support Library* instead of **AndroidX** in your project.

When you change compileSdkversion/targetSDKversion from 27 to 29(or 30) you need to migrate AndroidX into your project.

(Why you need to migrate Androidx? Because the highest Support Library version is 28, but you want to use your app above 28.)

Here is some help how to migrate AndroidX into your project:

- [Migrating to AndroidX](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)
- [Migrating to AndroidX: tips, tricks, and guidance](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-to-androidx-tip-tricks-and-guidance-88d5de238876)

Comment: i have tried to migrate to androidX but i'm facing some problems can you help me please ? i will send you my source code if you want please .

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c2GXtbmgA7Y
Here is a video of how to migrate Androidx into your project. ( And get some explanation.)